# Spring Data Solr with Solr 4.1 multicores

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data-solr

```
    Trying to implement Spring-Data-Solr with Solr 4.1 multicores,
```

At server startup getting following exception, I guess it expecting a default   constructor somewhere. So, is there a limitation of spring-data-solr with solr muticores implementation, here is my implementation,

### repositories

```
    public interface MembershipDocumentRepository extends
            CustomMembershipDocumentRepository,
            SolrCrudRepository<MembershipDocument, String> {
    }


 created 'repository' manually instead of autowiring/injection.......

    @Service
    public class RepositoryMembershipIndexService implements MembershipIndexService {   
        @Autowired
        private SolrTemplate solrMembershipTemplate;

        private MembershipDocumentRepository repository = new SolrRepositoryFactory(
                this.solrMembershipTemplate)
                .getRepository(MembershipDocumentRepository.class);

        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void addToIndex(Membership membershipEntry) {
            MembershipDocument document = MembershipDocument.getBuilder(
                    ...           
            repository.save(document);
        }
    }
```

### applicationContext-solr.xml

```
        <solr:repositories
            base-package="net.pegonwheels.spring.datasolr.domain.repository.solr" />
        <beans profile="prod">
            <solr:solr-server id="solrMembershipServer" url="${solr.server.url.membership}" />
            <bean id="solrMembershipTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
                <constructor-arg ref="solrMembershipServer" />
            </bean>
        </beans>
```

### exception

```
    At server startup getting following exception, I guess it expecting a default constructor somewhere. So, is there a limitation of spring-data-solr with solr muticores implementation. Can somebody please help me, thanks a ton in advance.
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryMembershipIndexService' defined in file [/home/rupanjan/Installations/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/pegonwheels-server/WEB-INF/classes/net/pegonwheels/spring/datasolr/domain/service/RepositoryMembershipIndexService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.pegonwheels.spring.datasolr.domain.service.RepositoryMembershipIndexService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: Can you please provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Hi Christoph, just updated the stacktrace in the post ..

Comment: I guess `SolrTemplate` is still null when `new SolrRepositoryFactory` is called. Please add the Interface `InitializingBean` to your `RepositoryMembershipIndexService` and create `MembershipDocumentRepository` whithin `afterPropertiesSet()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: SolrTemplate is null, getting following exception ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryMembershipIndexService' defined in file [/home/rupanjan/Installations/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/pegonwheels-server/WEB-INF/classes/net/pegonwheels/spring/datasolr/domain/service/RepositoryMembershipIndexService.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property update found for type void

Comment: you have to provide an implementation for your `CustomMembershipDocumentRepository`. like `new SolrRepositoryFactory(this. solrMembershipTemplate).getRepository(MembershipDocumentRepository.class, new CustomMembershipDocumentRepositoryImpl(solrMembershipTemplate));`

Answer (score 0):

in code u have

```
private MembershipDocumentRepository repository = new SolrRepositoryFactory(this.solrMembershipTemplate)
       .getRepository(MembershipDocumentRepository.class);
```

but your `MembershipDocumentRepository` can not be build with out custom implemention of `CustomMembershipDocumentRepository`.

if you implemented it check the name.it must be in the same package as `MembershipDocumentRepository` and named `MembershipDocumentRepositoryImpl` ( this is the default naming for it.

Comment: i just answered a question from 6 month ago. why it is not closed? :-)