# How to configure Spring Data Solr with Repositories for multiple cores

Tags: spring, solr, repository, spring-data-solr

Is there a detailed and complete explanation for setting up spring data with solr using repositories with multicore support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only dependency that need to be used for spring-data-solr is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It downloads solrj dependency and **this must not be overridden with later versions of solrj**.
Also It is always preferable to use HttpSolrServer over EmbeddedSolrServer which is what we will be working with.

The Configuration class should look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(value = "com.package.",multicoreSupport = true)
public class SolrConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SolrServer solrServer() throws Exception
    {
        HttpSolrServerFactoryBean f = new HttpSolrServerFactoryBean();
        f.setUrl("http://localhost:8983/solr");
        f.afterPropertiesSet();
        return f.getSolrServer();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrServer solrServer) throws Exception
    {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServer());
    }
}
```

The document entity should contain information about which core they belong to

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core1")
public class Document1
{
    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    /**other attributes**/
}
```

The other document should be

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core2")
public class Document2
{
    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    /**other attributes**/
}
```

Now the best part is you are already done. Simply setting up repository in the plain old way does the trick

```
public interface SolrCore1Repository extends SolrCrudRepository<Document1,String>
{
    // optional code
}
```

the other repo is like

```
public interface SolrCore2Repository extends SolrCrudRepository<Document2,String>
{
    // optional code
}
```

Once solr is running on the url specified and it has fields according to the pojo, you are done.